# printf unknown number of arguments

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell function that prints the name of a student, his surname and then a sequence of grades (output by another function). This sequence can consist of anywhere between 1 and 20 numbers. 
printf however, demands that output be formatted and I have written something like

```
printf "Name: %s\nSurname: %s\nGrades: %s\n"
```

But this is hopeless as if there is more than one grade, the output is completely unintelligible - it seems as it starts interpreting the next strings as again Name, Surname, etc, in a cyclic fashion. Can anybody assist me on how I should do the formatting for Grades?

Comment: How are you storing them, and how do you want to print them?

Comment: They are the values returned by an awk '{print somefield}' and I want to display them in the same line separated by a whitespace, as in 
Grades: 14 15 13 15 14 13 13 13 13 13 12

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /bin/bash
printf "Name: %s\nSurname: %s\nGrades:"
printf " %s" $(echo 1 2 3 4 5 6)        # replace by the grades
printf "\n"
```

Comment: One more problem. The output of the awk is in newlines and if I try to output it with spaces on the same line it won't work. In other words, using your example, I get grades in this format 123456. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Karl Sounds like you missed the space before the `%` in `printf " %s"`

Comment: @choroba I mean before that phase. the echo in the second line gets fed numbers without spaces and nothing seems to change it. Weird not even a sed 's/\n/' '/'

Comment: Include more details. Try running the script with `set -xv` to see more details.